# GRID как убрать вертальное расстяжение?

Tags: html, css, grid

Использую grid, задал 12 колонок, слева 6 колонок должен занимать текст, например:

1. дата
2. title
3. текст
4. кнопка

Также нужно, чтобы справа была картинка, весьма высокая. Она же занимает 6 остальных колонок.
Я написал, что текст - 6 колонок + добавил grid-rows: 1, 2, 3 и тд, чтобы текст стал в правильный ряд, потому что там есть последовательность.

Когда же я добавляю картинку, пишу ей что должна занимать начиная с 7 колонки до последней - она становится справа, но растягивает первый текст - дату, на свою высоту. Как можно игнорировать высоту картнки, чтобы текст не расстягивался на высоту картинки? (получается первый ряд расстянулся)

Comment: Добавьте в ваш вопрос ваш код.

Comment: вслепую, картинку надо так же и по строкам растянуть как по колонкам. должно получиться что то такое: `#you_img{grid-row: span *;}` где * - кол-во строк на которое надо растянуть картинку. для большей корректности - нужны исходники, или хотя бы больше подробностей. или так `#you_img{grid-row: 1 / *;}` тут * уже номер последней строки